# Is the current Python Beanstalkc client implementation non-blocking?

Tags: python, api, sockets, twisted, beanstalkd

I'm writing a socket API using twisted framework which needs to write to beanstalkd in a deferred, is the current Python Beanstalkc client implementation non-blocking?

I've searched extensively on Stackoverflow for answers about this matter without luck, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently available beanstalkc v0.3.0 uses blocking socket I/O operations.